# Why here the condition in the if statement is not able to satisfy

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart

here the userPassword.text and userName.text are the texteditingcontrollers which contain the value that user has just entered . and then i am comparing them with already saved values in the user object. i am not able to do it. but when i compare using a constant string it is working like if (userName.text == "hardik" && userPassword.text == "hardik@1"){ } this code is working. but not when i compare using user model .

Please help...

```
   MyTextButton(
                buttonName: 'Sign In',
                onTap: () {
                  for (var user in registeredUsers) {
           
                    if ( user.userName == userName.text && user.userPassword == 
   userPassword.text) {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => HomeScreen(registeredUsers),
                        ),
                      );
                      
                    } else {
                      print("Invalid Credintials");
                    }
                  }
                },
                bgColor: Colors.white,
                textColor: Colors.black87,
              ),
```

Comment: Are `user.userName` and `userName.text` both `String`?

Comment: Yes. Because in user object name and password are stored as string and in userName.text .text returns string from texteditingcontroller

Comment: Have you tried log the value of the four variable before the `if` check to verify that they actually contain the expected value?

Comment: Yes they are equal.